# Is one of the searched strings in every element of a list

Tags: r, string, list

I have a list of strings, which I split into a list and 2 strings the I want to look for

```
string <- c("ABC, BCD, DAB", "BCA, CDA, ABDA")

s1 <- "AB"

s2 <- "CD"
```

Divided by the `", "`, I want to see if in each element of the list created by `strsplit()`, I can find either of the the strings I look for.

The results should therefore follow this logic:

for the first string: TRUE, TRUE, TRUE --> TRUE

for the second string: FALSE, TRUE, TRUE --> FALSE

Can I do this using dplyr?

Comment: I don't understand. If we define `str_list = strsplit(string, ", ")` then `str_list` is `list(c("ABC", "BCD", "DAB"), c("BCA", "CDA", "ABDA"))`. Please explain to me how we get from there and `s1 <- "AB"` to `TRUE, TRUE, TRUE`.

Comment: I can see, for example, that `"AB" is part of "ABC" and "ABDA", so I could see that as `TRUE, TRUE`, but I'm confused why you have 3 `TRUE`s. And I also see `"CD"` in `"BCD"` and `"CDA"`...

Comment: I need to end up with 2 elements of the list, each with 3 elements in this case. I intend to check whether all 3 of those elements include at least one of the strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `purrr` solution:

```
string_list <- strsplit(string, ", ")

library(purrr)

map_lgl(string_list, ~ all(grepl(s1, .x) | grepl(s2, .x)))

#or
library(stringr)

map_lgl(string_list, ~ all(str_detect(.x, s1) | str_detect(.x, s2)))
```

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr` isn't really the right tool here. In base R, it's a one-liner:

```r
lapply(strsplit(string, ', '), \(x) all(grepl(paste(s1, s2, sep = '|'), x)))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] FALSE
```